# How to toggle the "hide keyboard button" on android one

Tags: android

, running android 11 , nokia g20

was wondering how to remove the whole hide keyboard button / bar area on android one , this is a feature on one ui and other roms but not android one/stock android

i've seen people moving the whole user interface down to hide it through adb but i dont wanna change the whole UI , is there a way to just hide this bar while typing ? using adb or any method ?